# chrome.tabs.sendMessage: “Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist” on cached pages only

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've read through all of the related errors, and I think this case is a bit different. I'm trying to send a message from the background context to a content script. E.g.

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    currentWindow: true,
    active: true
}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
        name: name,
        args: args
    }, function(response){
        if (!response) return callback('You tried to message a tab that does not exist');
    });
});
```

This will throw a `Port error` if the open tab was loaded before the extension was installed. To recreate:

1. Open a new tab and load a web page
2. Navigate to the extensions tab and reload the local unpacked extension
3. Navigate back to the web tab and invoke the extension via a Browser Action--it will throw the `Port error` unless the web page is manually reloaded.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sending a message, [programatically insert a content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) and use the callback's results:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    currentWindow: true,
    active: true
}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
        code: 'location.href',
        runAt: 'document_start',
        allFrames: false        // Run at the top-level frame only to get
                                // just one result
    }, function(results) {
        var result = results[0];
        console.log(result); // Example
    });
});
```

Instead of specifiying the code in a string, you can also run a file by using `file: 'code.js'` instead of `code: '...'`.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that might be the case. Maybe you know off hand--if a user invokes the Browser Action repeatedly on the same tab/url, will the script be executed repeatedly on that page, resulting in duplicate messages?

Comment: @ChristopherCliff Yes, but you can save a variable to see if the script has already run. Example: https://github.com/Rob--W/pdf.js/blob/57e623/extensions/chrome/insertviewer.js#L126-L128